# How to create instance of `Temporal.Instant` at specific date and time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc, ecmascript-temporal

I’m struggling with JavaScript’s [proposed new Temporal API](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/). What I am trying to do should be straight-forward, yet I fail to find a convincing solution. I must be missing something.

The task is as follows: **instantiate an object representation of an UTC datetime from variables for year, month, day, hour and minute**.

My thinking is as follows:

- we are talking UTC so I need a `Temporal.Instant`;
- `new Temporal.Instant()` requires the timestamp in nanoseconds so that doesn’t work;
- `Temporal.Instant.from()` requires a ISO datetime string, which would require me to generate a properly formatted piece of text from the five variables I have — this is possible but a bit of a hack and kinda defeating the purpose of using a datetime library;
- `Temporal.PlainDateTime.from()` has the right design, as it accepts an object like `{ year, month, day, hour, minute }`;
- so then all we need to do is creating an `Instant` from this `PlainDateTime`. This does not seem to be possible though? Other than through — once again — a datetime string or a timestamp in ns…?

This is silly! The use case here is super basic, and yet it’s not obvious (to me) at all how to address it.

I was expecting to be able to simply do something like:  `Temporal.Instant.from({ year, month, day, hour, minute });`

Now the best I can come up with is: `Temporal.Instant.from(year + '-' + String(month).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(day).padStart(2, '0') + 'T' + String(hour).padStart(2, '0') + ':' + String(minute).padStart(2, '0') + 'Z'); //`

Please tell me I’m bigtime overlooking something.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with `Temporal.Instant.from()`. If you want to hardcode an instant, it seems to be exactly the way to go.

Comment: You might use a *zonedDateTime* with timezone "UTC" or "Etc/GMT+0". Convert to an instant using *zonedDateTime.epochNanoseconds*. But there's not much difference between building an ISO string for the instant you want and building one object to convert it to another object. You could even use `Date.UTC(...)*1e3` to get nanoseconds since epoch (where `...` is values parsed from the input timestamp).

Comment: @Bergi Fair point. But let’s assume I don’t want to hardcode the datetime, but instead I have variables for year, month, day, hour, minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `PlainDateTime` [represents](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/#Temporal-PlainDateTime) "*a calendar date and wall-clock time that does not carry time zone information*". To convert it to an [exact time](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/ambiguity.html#wall-clock-time-exact-time-and-time-zones-in-temporal), you need to supply a timezone, using the [`toZonedDateTime` method](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindatetime.html#toZonedDateTime). By then ignoring calendar and timezone via the [`toInstant` method](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/zoneddatetime.html#toInstant), you can get the desired `Instant` instance.

So there's a few ways to achieve this:

- Create a `PlainDateTime` [from](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindatetime.html#from) an object, convert it to an instant by assuming `UTC` timezone:

  ```
  Temporal.PlainDateTime.from({year, month, day, hour, minute}).toZonedDateTime("UTC").toInstant()
  ```
- Create a `PlainDateTime` using [the constructor](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindatetime.html#new-Temporal-PlainDateTime), convert it to an instant by assuming `UTC` timezone:

  ```
  new Temporal.PlainDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute).toZonedDateTime("UTC").toInstant()
  ```
- Create a `ZonedDateTime` directly [from](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/zoneddatetime.html#from) an object, providing the timezone in there, then convert it:

  ```
  Temporal.ZonedDateTime.from({timeZone: 'UTC', year, month, day, hour, minute}).toInstant()
  ```
- Instead of going via a zoned datetime, you can also [get the instant](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/timezone.html#getInstantFor) that a `TimeZone` instance ascribes to a `PlainDateTime` object:

  ```
  Temporal.TimeZone.from("UTC").getInstantFor(Temporal.PlainDateTime.from({year, month, day, hour, minute}))
  new Temporal.TimeZone("UTC").getInstantFor(new Temporal.PlainDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute))
  ```
- If you wanted to hardcode the instant in your code, you could also directly create it [from](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/instant.html#from) an ISO string:

  ```
  Temporal.Instant.from("2022-10-23T02:50Z")
  ```
- If you are open to including the old `Date` methods, you could also use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to compute the [millisecond value for the instant](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/instant.html#fromEpochMilliseconds) - beware zero-based months:

  ```
  Temporal.Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(Date.UTC(year, month-1, day, hour, minute));
  ```

Try them for yourselves with your particular example:

```js
const year = 2022;
const month = 10;
const day = 23;
const hour = 2;
const minute = 50;

log(Temporal.PlainDateTime.from({year, month, day, hour, minute}).toZonedDateTime("UTC").toInstant());
log(new Temporal.PlainDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute).toZonedDateTime("UTC").toInstant());
log(Temporal.ZonedDateTime.from({timeZone: 'UTC', year, month, day, hour, minute}).toInstant());
log(Temporal.TimeZone.from("UTC").getInstantFor(Temporal.PlainDateTime.from({year, month, day, hour, minute})));
log(new Temporal.TimeZone("UTC").getInstantFor(new Temporal.PlainDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute)));
log(Temporal.Instant.from("2022-10-23T02:50Z"));
log(Temporal.Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(Date.UTC(year, month-1, day, hour, minute)));
```

```html
<script src="https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/playground.js"></script>
<script>function log(instant) { console.log(instant.epochSeconds); }</script>
```

Comment: This one is not too bad: `Temporal.ZonedDateTime.from({timeZone: 'UTC', year, month, day, hour, minute}).toInstant()` 

Comment: Although the “UTC” aspect is effectively alluded to twice, which is not the most elegant, but ah well. I suppose I’m asking for too much here. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "*alluded to twice*"?

Comment: Well, first I specify it when creating the `ZonedDateTime`: `Temporal.ZonedDateTime.from({timeZone: 'UTC', year, month, day, hour, minute})`. And then I basically specify it again by converting it into an `Instant`: `.toInstant()`.

I think the thing that confuses me is that as far as I understand `Instant` is simply a datetime in UTC, which makes me expect the APIs on `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` to be very similar. But they aren’t. They are actually very different. (Different constructor, no `add` or `subtract`, etc.)

Comment: No, an instant is not a datetime in utc. There's no date, there's no time, there's no timezone - it's just a timestamp. On which you could add/subtract absolute durations (in milliseconds), but which you can't do any calendar-based math. The docs write: "*An `Instant` is a single point in time (called "exact time"), with a precision in nanoseconds. No time zone or calendar information is present.*" Maybe this is not what you actually want?

Comment: The above comment is correct. If your data model includes years, months, days, or a time zone even if it's UTC, then Instant is not the type you should be using. It's only for timestamps.

Comment: There's intentionally no method that converts directly between PlainDateTime and Instant, because we found that whenever we wanted to use it, it was almost always a sign that we were misusing either the Instant or PlainDateTime type and should have used ZonedDateTime instead... (If you really need it, you can go via an intermediate ZonedDateTime, or use TimeZone's getInstantFor/getPlainDateTimeFor methods)

Comment: @ptomato Thanks, I had forgotten about `getInstantFor` - added to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I must admit that I find this concept of “timestamp that has no date or time” hard to grasp. A single point in UTC time has a year and a month, etc, even a time zone, just like any other time… ?? And a zoned datetime is no less exact than a timestamp??

Comment: @TimMolendijk A single point in UTC has date and and time *in UTC*. Yes, a `ZonedDateTime` no less exact than an `Instant`, they both can represent the same exact point in time, but the `ZonedDateTime` contains the used timezone as extra information (even if it's just "UTC" which you might consider as a default). But an `Instant` does not, it is part of many different date&times in different timezones, it just doesn't say where it belongs.

Comment: @Bergi Well, `Instant` says that it belongs in UTC. Which I don’s see how it negates calendering operations. The data I am working with is explicitly in UTC, as regional time zones are irrelevant to it. So that would suggest that I should use `Instant`, would you agree? But at the same time, I have clear calendering requirements on this data, for example: I take a UTC timestamp from my data, and I want to generate the timestamp for the point in time that comes exactly one month later. So now suddenly that would suggest I should use `ZonedDateTime`. And that’s how I ended up posting here. :)

Comment: @TimMolendijk "*`Instant` says that it belongs in UTC*" - no it doesn't, an instant does not belong to any particular timezone, that's the whole point. It's a nanosecond offset to some arbitrary (but agreed-on) fixed epoch, nothing more.

Comment: @TimMolendijk "*The data I am working with is explicitly in UTC*" - that would suggest you should use `ZonedDateTime`s that explicitly always use the UTC timezone. It would not suggest the usage of `Instant`s, or stronger: it would suggest not to use `Instant`s - what you want are UTC dates.

Comment: @Bergi Alright, clear.

For your information, this is the article (and section) that I had based my view on: https://2ality.com/2021/06/temporal-api.html#the-core-classes-of-the-temporal-api. I suppose it is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @TimMolendijk Ah, yes, sentences like "*Class `Instant` represents global exact time. Its time standard is UTC*" are definitely misleading. I would have preferred to write "*For some operations (such as `.toString()`), `Instant` internally uses an ISO-8601 calendar and the UTC time zone, but those are not stored in instances.*" Notice that [the timezone is an argument to the `toString` method](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/instant.html#toString), UTC is just the default if not passed.

Comment: how do we add one day to the specific Instant? I tried 
**export const dayOne = Temporal.Instant.from(dayZero).add({ days: 1 })** but get **RangeError: Cannot use large units**

Comment: @Nikos You cannot. You can add 24h if that's what you want, but the length of a day depends on the date and the timezone. Use a `DateTime` instead of the instant.

Comment: I tried to do this: https://github.com/quantuminformation/drizzle-sqlite-recurring-events/blob/main/test/test-constants.ts#L36

Comment: @Nikos See the [`add` documentation](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/instant.html#add). Either drop the `.toInstant()` and `Instant.from`, or add `.toZonedDateTimeISO('UTC')` to convert the instant back to the `ZonedDateTime` you started with.

Comment: oh cool, i didnt know datetime has epocmillis

Answer (score 0):

The *Date* API will continue to exist forever and is pretty handy so it seems sensible to use it if it helps.

*Date.UTC* returns the number of milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch. *Temporal.instant* requires nanoseconds, so given an input object with `{year, month, day, etc.}` the only hassle is to deal with the nanoseconds using [*BigInt*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), which is not hard:

```js
// Object for 7 December 2022
let d = {
  year: 2022,
  month: 12,
  day: 7,
  hour: 3,
  minute: 24,
  second: 30,
  millisecond: 10,
  microsecond: 3,
  nanosecond: 500
}

// Convert to time value - nanoseconds since ECMAScript eopch
let timeValue = BigInt(Date.UTC(d.year, d.month-1, d.day, 
  d.hour, d.minute, d.second, d.millisecond)) * BigInt(1e6) +
  BigInt(d.microsecond * 1e3) + BigInt(d.nanosecond);

// 1670383470010003500
console.log(timeValue.toString());

// 2023-01-07T03:24:30.010Z
console.log(new Date(Number(timeValue/BigInt(1e6))).toISOString());
```

An *instant* can then be created as:

```
let instant = new Temporal.Instant(timeValue);
```

Comment: when I try this **export const dayOne = Temporal.Instant.from(dayZero).add({ days: 1 })** I get **RangeError: Cannot use large units** where dayZero is another instant

Comment: @Nikos—when used to add time to an instant, a [duration](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/duration.html) can only have non–zero values for time components. Year, month, week and day components must be zero. To [add those values](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/instant.html#add), convert the instant to a *Temporal.ZonedDateTime*, adding a calendar and timezone (so units of variable length like years, months and days) can be added in an appropriate context. Once added, convert back to an instant.

Comment: @nikos—please note @ptomato's comment below Bergi's answer: "*There's intentionally no method that converts directly between PlainDateTime and Instant, because we found that whenever we wanted to use it, it was almost always a sign that we were misusing either the Instant or PlainDateTime type and should have used ZonedDateTime instead*". If you want to add days, weeks, etc. you should likely be using *ZonedDateTime*.